# Liferay. Modify JournalArticle from ModelListener

Tags: liferay

I trying to modify JournalArticle assets (need to set categories depending of article layout parents). I managed to implement ModelListener for JournalArticle. In method **onAfterUpdate()** I have **JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateAsset()**.

In logs everything is fine. I have needed category id in parameters, but it doesn't appear in categories list in article when I open article editor in the next time.

Is it possible to save changes in model from ModelListener somehow or it's just for monitoring and I can't modify model from this listener?

Code (reduced version):

```java
package mypackage;

// imports

public class JournalArticleListener implements ModelListener {

    private void updateCategories(JournalArticle article) {
        try {
            long[] categoriesArray = getCategories(article);  // this works fine
            String[] tagsArray = getTags(article); // this also works fine

            JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateAsset(article.getUserId(), article, categoriesArray, tagsArray);
        } catch (PortalException ex) {
            // logger
        } catch (SystemException ex) {
            // logger
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeUpdate(Object model) throws ModelListenerException {
        updateCategories((JournalArticle)model);
    }

    // other abstract method implemented without any code inside
}
```

in liferay-hook.xml I have

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_0_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <model-listener>
        <model-listener-class>mypackage.JournalArticleListener</model-listener-class>
        <model-name>com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle</model-name>
    </model-listener>
</hook>
```

Comment: Could you possibly post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code looks fine but I can think of a few things you could try. Please let me know if this worked for you.

First. check to see if the article is approved. If the article is in the draft state the data won't reflected until it is approved.

Second. Instead of using a model listener try overwriting the service with the hook instead.

```xml
<service>
    <service-type>com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleService</service-type>
    <service-impl>com.example.hook.service.impl.JournalArticleServiceImpl</service-impl>
</service>
```

You'll need to implement its service wrapper, `JournalArticleServiceWrapper`.

Overwrite the update methods (there could be several) and call its parent method then do your logic. Like so:

```java
public JournalArticle someUpdateArticleMethod(Many params) SomeExceptions {
    JournalArticle journalArticle = super.someUpdateArticleMethod(params);

    // my code here.
}
```

Doing it by model listeners is definitely easier. Though I'm not sure that this is the actual problem, it maybe that there is an issue using onAfterUpdate to update the model since an infinite loop could be created.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I hook JournalArticleLocalService and it works fine for me. Can you explain why should I have it for the Service and LocalService classes, but not only for LocalService?

Comment: You're right, I was thinking that calls could go to both the "remote service" and the "local service". But really, the remote service will call the local service 99% of the time and it is the case for `JournalArticle`. So hooking the `*LocalService` should be sufficient.

Comment: @RP. can u plzzz help me on this question...as i am unable to get any solution on this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747253/adding-custom-methods-in-hook-environment/9753001#comment12407650_9753001